# Normal group and commutator subgroup question

Tags: group-theory

Let $N$ be a normal subgroup of a group $G$. If $x\in G' \cap N$, is it true that $x \in [G,N]$? 
I tried to write a product of commutators and set it equal to $n=n_1n_2$. Since
$N$ is normal in $G$, $n$ can be put in a suitable commutator form and so it 
belongs to $[G,N]$.

Answer (score 1):

No, hint: take $N=Z(G)$, the center of $G$ and look for a group with $G' \cap Z(G)$ non-trivial. In this case $[G,Z(G)]=1$.

Comment: Is the answer negative even if $N$ is not the center of $G$?

Comment: Yes, even if $N$ is not central. There are nilpotent groups with $\{1\} \lt [G,G'] \subsetneq G'$. So if you take $N=G'$ here, the statement won't be true.